# Sort data frame while keep original row id and dimension

Tags: r, sorting, numeric

What I want to do is very simple. I would like to sort this data frame `df`:

```
    Signal
1   18
2   0.043
3   549
4   9998
5   2.342
```

By `Signal`, in order to obtain this:

```
    Signal
4   9998
3   549
1   18
5   2.342
2   0.043
```

It's important that the original row IDs are conserved.

I tried `sort(df$Signal)` and `df[sort(df$Signal),]` but it gives me a list.

Comment: `df[order(df$Signal), ]` does this. Did that not work? Oh, I didn't see that you used `sort`. `order` should work

Comment: Thanks! Yes actually I had tried that too with `sort()` but it also gives me a list...(added this to the OP). So `sort()` is for lists and `order()` is for data frames?

Comment: Sorry. Actually your solution also gives me a list... `> df[order(df$Signal), ]
[1] 0.043 2.342 18 549 9998`

Comment: order is sort for two dimensional data. stick a minus in front of `df$signal` then, `df[order(-df$Signal), ]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `df` is a function in package stats, I will call your data frame `d`.

`order` does indeed do the job, but you need to supply `drop=FALSE` to `[` to prevent getting a vector (dropping a dimension).  The dimension is dropped by default when possible, and here it is possible.

```
d[order(d$Signal, decreasing=TRUE),, drop=FALSE]
    Signal
4 9998.000
3  549.000
1   18.000
5    2.342
2    0.043
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm :) I would never have thought about `drop=FALSE` let alone put two commas in a row. Interesting.

Comment: @biohazard `[` is just another function. It takes arguments than just x, y, and drop. see `?'['`

Comment: @rawr Indeed.  Try `'['(d, order(d$Signal, decreasing=TRUE),,drop=FALSE)`

Comment: @biohazard It is important to include `drop=FALSE` when writing scripts, where you don't know how many columns may be present.

Comment: I edited the title to include the scope of the answer as well.